# WordPress WP FullCalendar fetches 2 years old events

Tags: wordpress, fullcalendar

I’m not sure why but in the current month view instead of showing current or future events the calendar shows only old events (almost two years old events!).
It seems there is no connection between the viewed month and the events it displays. You can see the problem here http://jems.co.il/he/calendar/

Also I am not sure if the problem is in the event manager settings or the WP FullCalendar settings or maybe it's completely something else.

Comment: Have you tried to look at any of the code or debug it using your browser or server tools? Since you haven't provided any code it's impossible for us to help with that.

Comment: I wish I could provide the code but I'm not sure what code is causing the problem
it's a page (http://jems.co.il/he/calendar/) in a WordPress site and I was hoping someone has already encountered this type of strange behavior.

chrome console doesn't show anything suspicious... 
also rechecked all the related plugin settings and everything seems to be set correctly... I don't have a clue where did I go wrong :(

Comment: So like I said, do some basic debugging. On this occasion I've done it for you: I watched your page as it loaded, in the Network tools in the browser you can see it calls `http://jems.co.il/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=WP_FullCalendar&type=event&month=1&year=2019&start=1548547200&end=1551916800&_=1550530519146` to load the events. The page's source code backs up that this is the URL being used by fullCalendar. It looks like it sends correct data about the date it is requesting the events for.

Comment: The data returned has start and end dates which match the current month (e.g. `"start":"2019-01-04T01:45:00","end":"2019-01-04T01:45:00"` as one example). If they didn't, they wouldn't show up on the calendar view. So if you're saying the events returned are actually from a different year, then there's clearly some error in the server-side code of admin-ajax.php (or it dependents), and/or a problem with the database data where it's getting this information from. As I mentioned in my first comment, since you haven't provided any of that code or data, I can't help you fix it.

Comment: Hi. maybe it's basic debugging but unfortunately, it's not that basic for me, anyway, thank you for your insights, I do appreciate your help very very much, these findings will certainly help me to investigate further, thanks a lot 

Comment: If that level of debugging is not something you're familiar with I suggest you get up to speed with how to use your browser's Developer Tools to see what is happening to your web page in detail. You can find detailed documentation provided by all the major browser vendors, plus tutorials etc provided by others. Once you learn some of the fundamentals you'll find it saves you a lot of time and frustration! Your browser is actually almost a fully-fledged IDE under the hood. Anyway good luck with your investigation. If you get stuck looking at the server-side code, post it here.